# chart.js no display on mobile browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, chart.js

I ve created a line chart that is shown correctly on the pc web browser but it didn't show on the mobile version and the screen is white.

Try adding the responsive option but it did not work,And also set the canvas sizes below 50px.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "myurl",
    method: "GET",
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      var player = [];
      var score =  [];

      for(var i in data) {
        player.push("Player " + data[i].fecha);
        score.push(data[i].monto);
      }

      var chartdata = {
        labels: player,
        datasets : [
          {
            label: 'Player Score',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
            hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
            hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
            data: score
          }

        ]
      };

      var ctx = $("#mycanvas");

      var barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: chartdata,
        options: {
          responsive: true
        }
      });
    },
    error: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#chart-container {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
<title>ChartJS - BarGraph</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1> Grafica</h1>
  <div id="chart-container">
    <canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="Chart.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

THANKS!!

Comment: Did you mannaged to solve it?

Comment: Yes, u need help?

Comment: I did, but i figured it out now. Thank you :)

Comment: What was the solution